# How to create one style that will have different values for different ui components in android

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm wandering if there is a way to apply one style that will handle different UI components that share some attributes in a different way, similar to the way css class can define how it handles each tag separately

for instance:

if i want the textview background to be black and the layout background to be blue
can i specify it in one style?

if so can i apply such a style to the entire fragment , without overwriting the app base theme?

Comment: Yes, you can. Your question is too broad, however. You obviously need to read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: i have but i didnt find a way to apply one style to 2 different UI componnents so it will work differentlly for each, also theme seems to go for an activity not for a fragment

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with styles and themes

here is a tutorial for you

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_styles_and_themes.htm